# Deny access to subdirectories using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Consider these files structures on web root directory :

```
files/1/1.jpg
files/1/2.jpg
files/2/1.jpg
files/2/3.jpg
files/3/6.jpg
files/3/8.jpg
files/4/1.jpg
```

I want to deny access to files inside folder 2 and 3 using htaccess file that exists in web root directory. I try  but nothing happend. Here's the code I used:

```
<FilesMatch "(2|3)\/*$" >
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Would you correct my mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: Are the `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` directories in the web root?

Comment: they are directories inside files directory which is inside web root.

Comment: If you read the Apache documentation, the regexp is matched against the "_basename (last component of filename)_"  hence it will _never_ match if you include path info in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If your htaccess file is in your web root, and the `files` directory is also in the web root, you won't be able to match against files in another (sub)directory. You can either try putting the `<FilesMatch>` in an htaccess file in the `files` directory, or you can use mod_rewrite in the htaccess file in your web root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^files/(2|3)/ - [F,L]
```

Comment: I guess the problem is something else, because I put <FilesMatch "(1|2)\.jpg$" > in the htaccess is in root directory and it works, maybe FilesMatch doesn't check directories,works only for files.

Comment: +1 for the Rewrite approach, though I would also suggest adding a `RewriteBase /` after turning the engine on.  As I explain above, the `Files` and `FilesNatch` directives only operate on the basename element of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

For optimal performance using htaccess, you should create a .htaccess file in each of the directories you want to protect:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Andreas, your use of the word 'optimal' is incorrect.  apache walks the request path and attempts to open any `.htaccess` that exists.  Each one that does exist generates an extra open/mmap/close.  On a share host the DOCROOT hierarchies are usually NAS served, so this will generate a VFAT cache miss and network I/O if this is the first req past `acregmin`.  The RewriteRule method in the DOCROOT .htaccess adds 10 μSec processing time but avoids this extra physical I/O.

Comment: I don't want to put a htaccess file in each directory. I need a overall htaccess in the root directory.